# Why is $\pi$ used in logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, notation

Why is $\pi$ used to denote probability in logistic regression?

Rather than something that does not create confusion with the more common use of $\pi$ as the circumference of a circle or the specific number $3.14 ...$?

Does using $\pi$ in logistic regression pertain some special meaning (like the more known $\pi=3.14...$) or is it just a symbol that has been chosen?

---

It seems to be pretty widely used:
http://www.google.com/search?q=logistic+regression+pi

Comment: Authors are free to use whatever notation they like, aren't they?  Did you come across this particular notation in a paper, or maybe some notes?

Comment: No $\pi$ on, e.g., German or English Wikipedia. And not so sure lmgtfy is appropriate when someone gives a comment on your question.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's because $\pi$ is related to the roman letter $p$, which is the first letter in "probability".  See http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/greek-alphabet.html.

Comment: $\pi$ used to be pretty standard for the population probability in the binomial, following the usual convention of Greek letters for parameters ($\mu$ for ***m***ean, $\sigma$ for ***s***tandard deviation,$\pi$ for ***p***robabiiity, and so on). It's less common now (you see $p$ used a lot more). Logistic regression is a model for a binomial proportion, so it's little surprise that it followed suit and sometimes also used $\pi$ to represent that binomial proportion it models.

Comment: It wasn't that bad question was it? I don't understand why it gets so much downvote. The question is relevant I think, because why is $\pi$ used, even when it does not seem to have anything to do with the more common $\pi$ of the circumfence of a circle.

Comment: It might be how the question was formulated that the community finds less than useful.  It implicitly assumes some kind of context--a paper, a book, some other written account--that has not been mentioned or quoted, but which nevertheless is crucial to understanding and answering the question.

Comment: It strikes me that although the question is not especially well-formulated - showing an *example* of the use of $\pi$ in logistic regression would help - it's both clear and answerable, so should probably be reopened.

Comment: @mavavilj, it may be the implied rudeness of lmgtfy in response to a comment prompting you to provide the appropriate context for your question. I didn't downvote this, but I was tempted to by that. Note that at least 9 people (including me & in addition to the author) seem to agree w/ Christoph Hank's comment, but there are only 5 downvotes to the question.

Comment: @gung I just used lmgtfy, because it's the only easy way to share Google links. Otherwise one'd have to edit Google addresses directly.

Comment: That seems reasonable, @mavavilj, but it doesn't come across well, particularly on the internet where paralanguage doesn't exist. It's true that lmgtfy, & its attendant connotations, is sometimes appropriate, but here you would have been better to edit the requested context (a concrete example or 2 w/, but not just, links) into the body of your question.

Comment: Your edit as to why you are concerned about the use of $\phi$ certainly improved the question. Then again, there are about 50 Greek and Latin letters combined. Hence, it is evident that probably all symbols will have many several widely used meanings across different disciplines that some users (I did not) maybe also downvoted because the answer to your question might be a simple "why not?".

Comment: (-1) A quick look at the hits in your Google search indicates that "pi" often refers to "$p_i$", not the Greek letter "$\pi$"!

Comment: @whuber Can the question still be improved or should it be deleted altogether?

Comment: Kind of an old question but two things, the "PI" function in logistic regression, a (special case of the gamma function)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Pi_function] is an upper case PI: Π. Second, you are confusing the numerical value of  with a choice of a letter to designate a type of function. Like so many things in mathematics, it's called a Π function because it is. May as well ask why a gamma function is called that.

Answer (score 9):

Because $\pi$ is the standard symbol for the unknown population value following the usual convention of using Greek letters and reserving the Roman for sample values.